# Excel VBA - Compare values across worksheets and delete the rows on a specific worksheet where the values match

Tags: excel, rows, vba

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CopyDataFromTemporarySheet()
    Dim checkCellSheet_1 As String
    Dim checkRangeSheet_2 As String
    Dim answer As Long
    Dim sheetName As String


    checkCellSheet_1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value
    checkRangeSheet_2 = AllWeldersData.range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Value
    sheetName = WQTR_Form.wqtrNumberText.Text


    If checkCellSheet_1 <> checkRangeSheet_2 Then
        range("A3:XFD3").Copy AllWeldersData.range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        answer = MsgBox("A record in ""All Welders Data"" with the WQTR Number: " + checkCellSheet_1 + _
                        " already exists.  Clicking Yes will overwrite the older" _
                        + " record with this new version.  Would you like to continue?" _
                        , vbYesNo, "Record Already Exists.")

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Worksheets("All Welders Data").Activate
            '****
            '*Delete the entire row where CheckRangeSheet_2 is
            '***
            Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
            range("A3:XFD3").Copy AllWeldersData.range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is what it does (except for the missing code where the asterisks are located):  It looks at a value in a cell (checkCellSheet_1) and compares it to the values in the range (column "B", checkRangeSheet_2) on the All Welders Data sheet.  If a match is found it displays a message box.

If the answer is yes it copies a row from the active sheet and pasts it as the last row.

What I am  missing and can't seem to get my head around today, is how to delete the row where the matching value was found on All Welders Data sheet.  I have tried various things but I keep getting a type mismatch warning or an invalid qualifier.  I am sure this simple and I am just not seeing the forest for the trees.  Somehow, I need to get the row number returned for the checkRangeSheet_2 valriable...I think.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you declare an integer or long variable which will hold the row number (e.g. x) then use `x = Application.WorkSheetFunction.Match(checkCellSheet_1, checkRangeSheet_2, 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

My original code modified slightly:

```
Private Sub CopyDataFromTemporarySheet()
    Dim checkCellSheet_1 As String
    Dim checkRangeSheet_2 As String
    Dim answer As Long
    Dim sheetName As String

    checkCellSheet_1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value
    checkRangeSheet_2 = AllWeldersData.range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Value
    sheetName = WQTR_Form.wqtrNumberText.Text

    If checkCellSheet_1 <> checkRangeSheet_2 Then
        range("A3:XFD3").Copy AllWeldersData.range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        answer = MsgBox("A record in ""All Welders Data"" with the WQTR Number: " + checkCellSheet_1 + _
                        " already exists.  Clicking Yes will overwrite the older" _
                        + " record with this new version.  Would you like to continue?" _
                        , vbYesNo, "Record Already Exists.")

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Call DeleteRowsWithDuplicateWQTRNumber 'ADDED THIS LINE
            Worksheets(sheetName).Activate  'ADDED THIS LINE
            range("A3:XFD3").Copy AllWeldersData.range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I added two lines in the `If answer = vbYes...` One to call another sub (see it below)  and the other to make sure the active sheet is correct when the exectution returns to this point.

The new sub follows:

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithDuplicateWQTRNumber() 'ADDED THIS SUB
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim wqtrNumber

    Worksheets("All Welders Data").Activate

    lastRow = AllWeldersData.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count
    wqtrNumber = WQTR_Form.wqtrNumberText.Text

    For counter = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(counter, 2) = wqtrNumber Then
        Rows(counter).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This activates the sheet where the row will be deleted, finds the last row in the current region, looks for matches to the "wqtrNumber" (from a field in my user form but could just as easily be a cell reference), and finally deletes any rows where it finds a match.

Then execution returns to the previous sub and pastes in a row from another sheet (where the matching value exists which was also taken from the user form).

It took a bit of trial and error on my part but I have tested it multiple times and it works.

**UPDATE - THE ABOVE CODE IS FLAWED**

For anyone who is looking for a solution that actually works:  After further testing I realized that the above code does not work properly.  I revised it and have tested several hundred times and everything does what it supposed to do!  The revised code is below.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wqtrNumber As String 'Global Variables
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim counter_1 As Long
Dim counter_2 As Long

Private Sub CopyDataFromTemporarySheet()
    Dim checkCellSheet_1 As String
    Dim checkRangeSheet_2 As String
    Dim answer As Long

    checkCellSheet_1 = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 2).Value
    checkRangeSheet_2 = AllWeldersData.range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Value
    wqtrNumber = WQTR_Form.wqtrNumberText.Text
    lastRow = AllWeldersData.range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.count

    For counter_1 = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If checkCellSheet_1 = checkRangeSheet_2 Then
        answer = MsgBox("A record in ""All Welders Data"" with the WQTR Number: " + checkCellSheet_1 + _
                        " already exists.  Clicking Yes will overwrite the older" _
                        + " record with this new version.  Would you like to continue?" _
                        , vbYesNo, "Record Already Exists.")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                Worksheets("All Welders Data").Activate
                Call DeleteRowsWithDuplicateWQTRNumber
                Worksheets(wqtrNumber).Activate
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        ElseIf checkCellSheet_1 <> checkRangeSheet_2 Then
            'Do Nothing!
        End If
        checkRangeSheet_2 = AllWeldersData.range("B" & counter_1).Value
    Next counter_1

    Worksheets(wqtrNumber).Activate
    range("A3:XFD3").Copy AllWeldersData.range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub

Sub DeleteRowsWithDuplicateWQTRNumber()

    Worksheets("All Welders Data").Activate

    For counter_2 = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(counter_2, 2) = wqtrNumber Then
        Rows(counter_2).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```